# Bulkloading xml's into Oracle table

Tags: sql, powershell, oracle

## Intro

We have some old(in my eyes) software at the place I work at the moment,

Some stuff needs to be done manually, for instance we need to insert a XML file into a Oracle table, which will trigger... *stuff*

I got annoyed by having to do this manually all the time,

So I decided to automate the process a bit with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and Oracle's sqlldr

My knowledge of Oracle is limited hence the asking for a review,

**What I did**

1. I have created a separate table, to which I am inserting my file.
2. That table has a trigger, to get the specified information, and insert it into the correct table (which is not up for review)
3. Created a powershell script to be able to load files in bulk into the table

## Code

*The sql script for creating the table*

```
CREATE TABLE mckdev.ogd_xml_table (
  id        NUMBER(10),
  xml       XMLTYPE,
  "IN_CON_LOG" NUMBER(1,0), 
  "ZIS_EVENT" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
);

ALTER TABLE mckdev.ogd_xml_table ADD (
  CONSTRAINT ogd_xml_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE mckdev.ogd_xml_table_seq;
```

*The load_data.ctl*

```
load data
infile ''
append
into table ogd_xml_table
fields
(  
    filename FILLER CHAR(100),
    xml lobfile( filename) terminated by eof
)
```

*The bulkloader.ps1*

```
$dataFiles = @(
    "filelist21.dat"
    "filelist22.dat",
    "filelist23.dat",
    "filelist25.dat",
    "filelist121a.dat",
    "filelist121b.dat",
    "filelist122a.dat",
    "filelist122b.dat"
)
$ctlFile = "$PSScriptRoot\load_data.ctl"

foreach ($f in $dataFiles) {
    (Get-Content $ctlFile) -Replace "infile '[^']*'", "infile '$($PSScriptRoot)\$($f)'" | Out-File $ctlFile -Encoding ASCII
    sqlldr mckdev@$SecretDatabase/$SecretPassword control=$ctlFile
}
```

An example `filelist.dat` only holds a reference to another XML file.

## Questions

- Currently I need to have multiple `.dat` file to be able to load them in bulk.

  One for each XML file I want to load into the table. Is there any way around this?
- Is this a correct approach or would you have done things differently?

Answer (score 1):

As the ctl file can't be parameterized you'll have to create them for each infile.

As it is quite small, I'd create it on the fly from a here string with the format operator.

This sample script just echoes to screen, the commands to write/execute sqlldr are commented out.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\24\CR_212133.ps1
$dataFiles = @(
    "filelist21.dat"
    "filelist22.dat",
    "filelist23.dat",
    "filelist25.dat",
    "filelist121a.dat",
    "filelist121b.dat",
    "filelist122a.dat",
    "filelist122b.dat"
)

$ctlFile = "$PSScriptRoot\load_data.ctl"

foreach ($dataFile in $dataFiles) {
@'
load data
infile '{0}'
append
into table ogd_xml_table
fields
(
    filename FILLER CHAR(100),
    xml lobfile( filename) terminated by eof
)
'@ -f $dataFile  #| Out-File $ctlFile -Encoding ASCII
    #sqlldr mckdev@$SecretDatabase/$SecretPassword control=$ctlFile
}
```

---

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\24\CR_212133.ps1
load data
infile 'filelist21.dat'
append
into table ogd_xml_table
fields
(
    filename FILLER CHAR(100),
    xml lobfile( filename) terminated by eof
)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
load data
infile 'filelist22.dat'
append
into table ogd_xml_table
fields
(
    filename FILLER CHAR(100),
    xml lobfile( filename) terminated by eof
)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
%<...snip...>%
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking back at it again, I realized I didn't need all those different `dataFiles`,
as all those `dataFiles` hold only a single reference with the full path to the XML file.

Instead I could get the path for each XML file and overwrite the single dataFile with the correct file path I want to execute.

- This makes adding another XML file to load, as easy as adding it to the directory I read the files from
- And removes the need for multiple `dataFiles`

---

```
$xmlDirectories = @(
    "directory1",
    "directory2"
)
$dataFile = "$PSScriptRoot\filelist.dat"
$ctlFile = "$PSScriptRoot\load_data.ctl"

foreach ($dir in $xmlDirectories) {
    foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$dir")  {
        $f.FullName  | Out-File $dataFile -Encoding ASCII
        sqlldr mckdev@$SecretDatabase/$SecretPassword control=$ctlFile
    }
}
```